# Calculating collision vector between two circles in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, physics, collision

I'm working on a game in SpriteKit similar to Air Hockey. It's pretty simple, but I am trying to make the physics relatively realistic.

Currently I'm trying to calculate the appropriate impulse vector when the player (a circular mallet) strikes a circular ball/puck.

I have access to:

- velocity of the player mallet (calculated with touchesMoved frame to frame)
- accurate collision detection using `func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`
- the exact point where the mallet contacts the ball: `contact.contactPoint`
- the direction vector for the ball: `contact.contactNormal.dx` and `contact.contactNormal.dy`

I believe my issue is more physics/math related. I can't figure out the impulse I should apply to the ball to be most realistic. I want to incorporate the velocity of the player and the direction vector so that the player can strike the ball and see a responsive impulse on the ball.

The impulse is in the format:
`ball!.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: ..., dy: ...))`

Any recommendations are appreciated!

Update: Here is some additional code from my game.

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)
    {
        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.ball.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue) && (contact.bodyA.contactTestBitMask == 25 || contact.bodyB.contactTestBitMask == 25) && bottomTouchForCollision == true
        {
            ball!.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "BottomVelocity")) * contact.contactNormal.dx, dy: CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "BottomVelocity")) * contact.contactNormal.dy))
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm using velocity of the player and the expected angle the ball would bounce off of the mallet, if the mallet was not moving. Something about it just feels off though and Im not sure what.

Comment: Consider the case of the ball hitting a stationary mallet.  It will reflect off with the same speed, and the final direction of motion is such that angle-of-incidence equals angle-of-reflection at the contact point.  Then for a mallet moving with velocity vector v, subtract v from all velocities to transform to the stationary-mallet case.  Calculate ball velocity in the transformed problem.  Then transform back by adding v to the result.  (If you're calculating it like that, you don't have to `applyImpulse`, just set the new velocity directly.)

Comment: What you're saying sort of makes sense but some things go a bit over my head. Would you mind elaborating with some code? I added to my original post how I am currently applying impulse now. I just really want to get this part accurate and responsive because its a major part of the game. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @bg2b I was wondering if you saw my comment above? I'm still trying to work through this issue. I understand most of what you said but some things I am confused about. I would really appreciate help :). If possible with either code or pseudocode. I get confused at "Then for a mallet moving with velocity vector v, subtract v from all velocities to transform to the stationary-mallet case. Calculate ball velocity in the transformed problem. Then transform back by adding v to the result." Been trying to fix this for weeks but keep hitting dead ends :/